# Clarification on pigeonhole principle for case of choosing $k$ elements from a set such that $2$ elements from the subset sum to a particular number

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, pigeonhole-principle

I have $20$ cards, each labelled $1$ to $20$, and I would like to find the minimum number of cards I have to select such that there will always be $2$ cards in the subset of cards selected, that add up to $21$.

The method I used to solve this question (which I am not sure of) is as follows:

First I list down the possible unique pairs of cards that add up to $21$, which are
$\{1, 20\}, \{2, 19\}, \{3, 18\}, \{4, 17\}, \{5, 16\}, \{6, 15\}, \{7, 14\}, \{8, 13\}, \{9, 12\} ,\{10, 11\}$
and there are $10$ unique pairs.

Then I applied the pigeonhole principle which states that for $kn+1$ pigeons, to be distributed into $n$ holes, there must be at least $k+1$ pigeons in each hole. In this case, I let the pairs be the "holes" and the cards be the "pigeons", and solved for $k$ to get $k=$${19}\over{10}$, and therefore, at least $3$ cards must be selected for there to always have $2$ cards that have a sum of $21$.

I am not sure if my solution is correct, and if I am using the pigeon hole principle correctly, and I think the selection of what to use for the "holes" is wrong. Can someone explain what is the right way to go about selecting the "holes" for this problem?

If I am correct, I am not sure why I am correct and why the selection of the "holes" as the pairs is correct. Can someone explain to me?

Comment: Sorry, I am not fully awake.  Your holes are fine, but your conclusion that three cards must be selected is incorrect.

Comment: "the pigeonhole principle which states that for $kn+1$ pigeons, to be distributed into $n$ holes, there must be at least $k+1$ pigeons in each hole." No, it states that there will be $k+1$ pigeons in *at least one* of the holes. In your case you want at least $2$ in one of the holes so $k=1$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis does this mean to say that I should not have rounded up the answer of K to 2?

Comment: No. You should not solve for $k$. Instead you should choose $k$ yourself, which is always an integer, according to what you want to achieve. In this case, $2$ cards in at least one pigeon hole.

Comment: Ok I think I understand the part where I misunderstood the principal

Comment: The worst case scenario here is that you pick $10$ numbers, one from each of your sets.  Therefore, you need to choose at least $11$ numbers to ensure that you will have both numbers from one of your sets.

Comment: Also, the word is principle, meaning rule, not principal, meaning first or highest in rank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pigeonhole principle is that if $kn+1$ (or more) "pigeons" are divided amongst $n$ "holes" then at least one of the holes contains at least $k+1$ pigeons.

Here, the holes are the pairs (so $n=10$), and you want to conclude that at least one pair contains at least $2$ pigeons, so $k+1=2$.

The answer is the number of cards selected, which corresponds to the number of pigeons. So this is $nk+1=11$.

An example which shows this is best possible is that if you only selected $10$ numbers, they could be the smallest $10$, in which case the maximum sum of any pair would be $19$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. I mistook $k$ to be the thing I needed to solve when it was actually $kn + 1$ that I needed to solve for.

Answer (score 0):

The number of cards to be selected is 11. Then there you have to choose at least two cards from the same two-subset.